# My Github project merged with all other projects

Tags: git, github

My github project merged all other project together.

After a long time I have used my github.  While pushing in new repository, it shows "failed to push some refs to 'origin'". So I followed the commands given on the github page on new repository.  After that it push to main.  But Here it pushes all other folder which is on my github page together.  Help me to extract all my other github project.

Comment: Make sure where did you run the git init command. If you can run the `git init` command on the parent directory, the `git` will track all of its child directories... Check this with the `ls-la` command and see where the hidden `.git` file is...

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you are pushing from the folder containing all other projects.

Try using `cd [project folder]` and then pushing to the respective repository.

For resolving the problem:

- Try deleting the all other project in the new repository from github page.Here's how you can do it.[Delete repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/deleting-files-in-a-repository#deleting-a-file)
- Check if you have any current repositories open in your code editor.If yes,close it.(In case of vscode:close the repository from *source control*.
- Now use publish to github or use terminal and use the same commands to push your required code to github